# Solve for $f(x)$ and $b$ in Riemann sum problem

Tags: calculus, integration

The following sum

$$ \sqrt{49-\frac{7}{n}^2}\cdot\frac{7}{n} + \sqrt{49-\frac{14}{n}^2}\cdot\frac{7}{n} + \cdots
 + \sqrt{49-\frac{7n}{n}^2}\cdot\frac{7}{n} $$

is a right Riemann sum for the definite integral

$$ \int_0^b f(x)\,dx
$$

Find $b, f(x)$ and the limit of these Riemann sums as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Would you share what you've tried? Remember that the general form of a Riemann sum is something like $\sum_n f(x_n) \Delta x$ - perhaps you can think of a way to subdivide an interval into $n$ equal pieces.

Comment: @user61527 Thanks! I actually managed to solve it by looking at another example problem, but your tip is helpful for getting a point in the right direction. I'll answer my own question with my solution in a bit.

Comment: I think you mean $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{49-\left(\frac{7k}{n}\right)^2}\cdot \frac{7}{n}$$, otherwise, the sign's negative inside the root. Parentheses are very important.

Answer (score 1):

The integral is: $\displaystyle \int_{0}^7 \sqrt{49 - x^2} dx$. It appears that your Riemann sum is mistyped because you missed an $n$ at the denominator and it is supposed to be $n^2$.